# Which is faster and more efficient, processing char by char as char or as stream?

Tags: c++, string, stream, flush

If I want to process a text file char by char before using it. What method is most efficient?

I can do this:

```
ifstream ifs("the_file.txt", ios_base::in);
char c;
while (ifs >> noskipws >> c) {
    // process c ...
}
ifs.close();
```

and this:

```
ifstream ifs("the_file.txt", ios_base::in);
stringstream sstr;
sstr << ifs.rdbuf();
string txt = sstr.str();
for (string::iterator iter = txt.begin(); iter != txt.end(); ++iter) {
    // process *iter ...
}
```

The final output will be splitted string based on char found while iterating.

Which is faster? Or maybe there's another more efficient way? Do I need to flush the `stringstream` for every character (I read somewhere that `flush` is affecting performance)?

Comment: I think you are doing premature optimization here. Try both cases, profile and optimize. I have a feeling this depends on compiler implementation and maybe even OS.

Comment: You should try and measure both.

Answer (score 1):

a) Measure (I'd guess that first one should be faster as it avoids extra allocation, but it is just a guess)

b) While it can indeed be a Really Bad case of premature optimization, if you really need the very best performance, try something along the lines of:

```
int f = open(...);
//error handling here
char buf[256];
while(1) {
  int rd = read(f,buf,256);
  if( rd == 0 ) break;
  for(const char*p=buf;p<buf+rd;++p) {
    //process *p; note that this loop can be entered more than once
  }
}
close(f);
```

I'm pretty sure that it will be very difficult to beat this code performance-wise (unless going into very low-level non-standard IO); however, it might easily happen that ifstream will produce comparable results. Or it might not.

NB: for C++ the difference provided by this technique (read fixed-size buffer, then scan buffer) is small and usually negligible, but for other languages it might easily provide up to 2x difference (has been observed on Java).

Answer (score 0):

Based on a crude test for a 20 mega byte file, this method loads the file in to one string in 0.1 second, versus 0.5 second for `rdbuf` method you had earlier. So basically there is no difference unless you are accessing lots and lots of files.

```
ifstream ifs(filename, ios::binary);
string txt;
unsigned int cursor = 0;
const unsigned int readsize = 4096;
while (ifs.good())
{
    txt.resize(cursor + readsize);
    ifs.read(&txt[cursor], readsize);
    cursor += (unsigned int)ifs.gcount();
}
txt.resize(cursor);
```